# JAWS is not reading dynamic values added to span element

Tags: wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have a scenario like, when a page gets loaded, some Ajax requests will be raised and the response will be painted inside `span` elements. All the updated `span` elements should be read once the screen got loaded.

I have added `aria-live = "polite"` and `role = "alert"` attributes to the `span` to make the content readable by JAWS. All the updated `span` elements are read some times or only the last updated `span` is read. This behavior is inconsistent. Can you help me to resolve this?

P.S: I have also tried `aria-live` with `assertive`, but facing the same issue here as well.

Comment: [role='alert'](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#alert) is implicitly an assertive live region. I doubt that it's the source of the problem, but worth noting that it is redundant.

Comment: I am having a similar issue to this where a dynamically updated span's content is not being read when Jaws gets to it. Jaws continues to read the old text that used to be present in this span. It is as if Jaws Virtual Buffer is not being updated. Where you able to solve your issue? I have also tried aria-live and also aria-controls on the button that triggers the span to be updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try hitting INSERT + ESCAPE key combination? This is for refreshing the screen when JAWS is on. If this doesn't work, can you please post the HTML markup here?